# DOM not accessible from Chrome extension after chrome version update content_scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Not sure which specific chrome version or the policy updates but from 3rd November 2022 only few users were having issue where "content_scripts" are not able to get access to DOM elements.

Below code is failing to fetch document

document.getElementsByTagName('video')

Answer (score 0):

I eventually landed up with below changes and it helped me to get the DOM access.

Added all_frames as true in the manifest.json for content_scripts and also gave access to all websites in the matches.

> "content_scripts": [{
> **"all_frames": true,**
> "js": ["/content/contentScript.js"],
> "matches": ["<all_urls>"]   }]